# Whether an FO(PFP) formula is totally defined is undecidable?

Tags: logic, model-theory, decidability

How can I show that the problem that : Whether an FO(PFP) formula is totally defined is not decidable?

I have these:

PFP-formula: partial fixed point formula.

A formula is totally defined if for all its subformulas of the form $[ PFP_{\overline x, X}\phi]\overline t$ the fixed point $F_\infty^{\phi}$ exists in every structure and for all assignments.

Every formula of partial fixed-point logic is equivalent to a
formula containing exactly one occurrence of the $PFP$ operator.

Trahtenbrot's theorem:Finite satsfiability is not decidable.

Comment: It seems there is a number of notions you give as granted. In my personal opinion, the more tags you put, the less you have to assume as well-known.